# Removing all commas from list in Python

Tags: python

My issue: I'd like to add all the digits in this string `'1.14,2.14,3.14,4.14'` but the commas are causing my sum function to not work correctly.
I figured using a strip function would solve my issue but it seems as though there is still something I'm missing or not quite understanding.

```
total = 0
for c in '1.14,2.14,3.14'.strip(","):
    total = total + float(c)
print total
```

I have searched how to remove commas from a string but I only found information on how to remove commas from the beginning or ending of a string.

Additional Info: Python 2.7

Comment: From the first string, are you expecting an answer of `10.56` or an answer of `30.0`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use the following:

```
# Get an array of numbers
numbers = map(float, '1,2,3,4'.split(','))

# Now get the sum
total = sum(numbers)
```

Comment: Maybe slightly less elegantly, `ast.literal_eval` will handle that string as well ...

Answer (score 4):

You don't want `strip`, you want `split`.

The `split` function will separate your string into an array, using the separator character you pass to it, in your case `split(',')`.

Answer (score 4):

Remove commas from `list`

Updated for Python3:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ''.join(str(a).split(','))
```

removes commas from list i.e.

```
[1,2,3,4,5]  --> [1 2 3 4 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this to remove commas and white spaces

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(*a, sep = "")
```

Output:-
12345

Answer (score 1):

You need `split` not `strip`.

```
>>> for c in '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'.split(","):
    print float(c)

1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
```

Or if you want a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [float(c) for c in '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'.split(",")]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

And for getting the sum,

```
>>> sum(map(float, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'.split(",")))
45.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
values=input()         
l=values.split(",")   
print(l)
```

With values=1,2,3,4,5

the result is ['1','2','3','4','5']

Answer (score 0):

This will add all of the digits in the first string in your question:

```
sum(float(x) for x in '1.14,2.14,3.14,4.14' if x.isdigit())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there seem to be a pattern in your input list of floats, this one-liner generates it:

```
>>> sum(map(float, ','.join(map(lambda x:str(x+0.14), range(1,5))).split(',')))
10.559999999999999
```

And since it doesn't make much sense joining with commas and immediately splitting by commas, here's a little saner piece of code:

```
>>> sum(map(float, map(lambda x:str(x+0.14), range(1,5))))
10.559999999999999
```

---

And if you actually meant you wanted to sum single digits and not the actual floating-point numbers (although I doubt it since you cast to float in your sample code):

```
>>> sum(map(int, ''.join(map(lambda x:str(x+0.14), range(1,5))).replace('.', '')))
30
```